# Mini Cooper R56 Completely Dead

Tags: electrical, mini-cooper, immobilizer

I drove mini cooper R56 for a very short distance for about 4 minutes, the whole car died completely. The battery was working fine, everything else seemed fine but the car died altogether.

Observations: All electronics systems seem dead, no light when I open the door, no unlocking by key FOB, no sparking when battery is jumped (eventhough battery is fine, tested several times, which indicates open loop)

Prior Issues: The car was hissing while acceleration due to spark plugs being worn out and I have already had them purchased but didnt get chance to replace.

To be honest this have happened once in the past but all electronics came back to life after 4 hours automatically but I couldnt diagnose what has happened.

Question: Could ECU have shut down all the electronics as a safety measure? Or could this be due to some electric trip somewhere in the circuit or could this be BCM?

---

Update: Found someone else also experiencing exactly similar issue in [Mini Forum](https://www.mini2.com/threads/cooper-goes-completely-dead.171266/), but unfortunately no valid solution so far.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "...key getting stuck..." Does the car have a physical key? Could it no longer be inserted, or removed, or turned from one position to another?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, the car has electronic key, but it is [transponder like](https://store.bimmernav.com/products/mini-cooper-replacement-key), so there is a push button. So when you insert this key by pushing there is a release mechanism, you push again and the key comes out and engine is stopped.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "key getting stuck...?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, when the car died, i tried to release the key, by pushing it again, but it never came out, so that what I mean it got stuck. But when the car came back to life, I was able to make the trip and retrieve the key.

Comment: If the car's electrical system had turned off, then I'd expect that the key release action would fail for lack of electricity. This is consistent with a total power failure, but does not explain why the failure occurred. If the car has an OBD or EOBD onboard diagnostic port, you should start by having the codes read, as there may be an electronic record that will assist the diagnosis. Your thought of a theft system issue is a reasonable one,

Comment: I would suggest you have an issue with the power connection at the battery or where those leads land (body or power delivery). I've seen it many times where the main power will get lost then come back after some time. This could be due to corrosion or a lose connection. Check your battery cable ends for corrosion as well as if there is any bulging in the cables themselves. Just a thought, because it's a long shot.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I checked the battery leads and there is no corrosion, plus the battery is relatively new, I replaced it 2 weeks ago. I even removed the battery cables and put them back on to see if it should initiate a restart of the system but at no good end. There were couple of people that came to help to see if jump starting would help but the battery was perfectly fine. I reckon that I would really have to trace the whole electrical connection one by one to see if there is any loose end or corrosion somewhere.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica yes, i tried googling the theft system on mini cooper but couldnt fine much on the topic. Also the fact that it happened after i made a short trip, the car was running fine. So maybe there was some electrical trip somewhere that triggered the anit-theft system or maybe a loose connection somewhere. But these are just my hypothesis.

Comment: You checked the battery connections _at the battery_, but you should also check all the big-wire connections _at the other end of each cable_, where the cables connect to the car's ground and to the starter. It is possible, 'tho unlikely, that one of the cables has an intermittent internal failure.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, i guess your point is quite likely, I shall have an electrician check out all the major wirings as I am afraid to experience this ordeal again. Minis dont have way to put the gear to neutral once the car electrical dies to have them towed over breakdown.

Comment: Your course of action sounds prudent to me. I wouldn't want to risk getting stranded either.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 you were right, it was power distribution control module that is just next to the battery. Should had tried to use voltmeter and located where the voltage stops. I had to pay hefty price along with the breakdown service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested by auto electrician. POWER DISTRIBUTION BOX CONTROL MODULE was bad that takes the power from the battery and passes on. Not sure how exactly is this module different from the fuse box next to wheel well.